# JQuery scroll background image of a div

Tags: jquery, scroll, background-image

I want to simply move the background image down in the div (which is smaller than the image) so that the image drifts across the visible area of the div (image is 705 high, div is 215px high).

I got this from other posts, however it doesn't seem to work :(

Any ideas? - no errors, but nothing hapens

in HTML I have

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

and css;

```
#banner {
    background-image: url(/media/residential-services-705.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 215px;
    width: 940px;
    background-position: left 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

And javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bouncebanner();
});

function bouncebanner(){
    $('#banner').stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 -490px)"}, 
        {duration:5000}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
backgroundPosition: '0 -490'
```

dont use px and brackets that might be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to animate only one of the axis (either X or Y), you should target that specific axis as follows:

```
// X Axis, use backgroundPositionX //
function bouncebanner(){
    $('#banner').stop().animate({backgroundPositionX: -490}, 5000);
}

// Y Axis, use backgroundPositionY //
function bouncebanner(){
    $('#banner').stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: -490}, 5000);
}
```

Also, consider adding a starting location for the background image as this will prevent image jumping in older browsers as follows:

```
background: url(/media/residential-services-705.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
```

[JSFiddle for X Axis](http://jsfiddle.net/Btfsg/1/)

[JSFiddle for Y Axis](http://jsfiddle.net/Btfsg/)

I hope this helps!